# How can be made multiple request using request and bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is there away to make these line of code to look like one?

```
r1 = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g187895-d235993-Reviews-Hotel_Alessandra-Florence_Tuscany.html')
r2 = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g187895-d235993-Reviews-or5-Hotel_Alessandra-Florence_Tuscany.html#REVIEWS')
r3 = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g187895-d235993-Reviews-or10-Hotel_Alessandra-Florence_Tuscany.html#REVIEWS') 
r4 = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g187895-d235993-Reviews-or15-Hotel_Alessandra-Florence_Tuscany.html#REVIEWS')
r5 = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g187895-d235993-Reviews-or20-Hotel_Alessandra-Florence_Tuscany.html#REVIEWS')
r6 = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g187895-d235993-Reviews-or25-Hotel_Alessandra-Florence_Tuscany.html#REVIEWS')
r7 = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g187895-d235993-Reviews-or30-Hotel_Alessandra-Florence_Tuscany.html#REVIEWS')
r1.text
r2.text
r3.text
r4.text
r5.text
r6.text
r7.text
```

Comment: you've to put your links inside a list and then loop over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
links = ['site1', 'site2']

def main(links):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for link in links:
            r = req.get(link)
            print(r.text)


main(links)
```

Comment: and it will replace all of that part?

Comment: where i can find more info about how can i create  ? Because i have this to deal '''soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.text,'html.parser')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.text,'html.parser')
soup3 = BeautifulSoup(r3.text,'html.parser')
soup4 = BeautifulSoup(r4.text,'html.parser')
soup5 = BeautifulSoup(r5.text,'html.parser')
soup6 = BeautifulSoup(r6.text,'html.parser')
soup7 = BeautifulSoup(r7.text,'html.parser')results1 = soup1.findAll(class_='IRsGHoPm')
 '''

Comment: how can i extract text , like this from main(links) soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.text,'html.parser')